# How can I identify unique visitors to my Java Spring web app to display "X number of users currently online"?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a web app build with Java & Spring MVC.

I'm putting it online for demo purposes (in a "free tier" EC2 t2.micro instance) and I want to see on the main page how many unique visitors are currently online.

Note: Users do not log in, they just visit the site.

How can I determine if the requests are coming from a new unique user?  Can I see the incoming IP address and/or something else?

Comment: You cannot. At least not with 100% accuracy. If you pass along a cookie with, e.g., a UUID, the client can delete the cookie. If you track the IP, the client can use a VPN/TOR/other techniques to obfuscate its IP.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It doesn't have to be foolproof, just helpful to get a sense of number of concurrent visitors.  I'm thinking maintaining a list the incoming IP addresses and removing them from the list after 10 minutes of inactivity would probably work for me.